# Error "getcwd() failed: No such file or directory" when trying to run from VS in Docker

Tags: visual-studio, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I have a project set up to run locally in Docker with docker-compose. Until recently, it's been working fine. I don't believe I changed anything that should affect this (except maybe a VS upgrade?), and I've even tried rolling back to an older commit. In all cases, I'm now getting an error message, which appears in Visual Studio's output window as:

```
docker exec -i f93fb2962a1e sh -c ""dotnet"  --additionalProbingPath /root/.nuget/packages --additionalProbingPath /root/.nuget/fallbackpackages  "bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/MattsTwitchBot.Web.dll" | tee /dev/console"
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
  It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs
  Did you mean to run .NET Core SDK commands? Install a .NET Core SDK from:
      https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

I've tried a variety of different things (changing the base image in the Docker file, deleting old images and containers, and more) but I keep getting the same error message. The weird thing is that when I do a File->New, Visual Studio generates a very similar looking Docker file and it works fine. I have no idea what the problem is, but I'm hoping someone here can spot it.

[My full repo is available on Github](https://github.com/mgroves/MattsTwitchBot). Here is the docker for the asp.net core project:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MattsTwitchBot.Web/MattsTwitchBot.Web.csproj", "MattsTwitchBot.Web/"]
COPY ["MattsTwitchBot.Core/MattsTwitchBot.Core.csproj", "MattsTwitchBot.Core/"]
RUN dotnet restore "MattsTwitchBot.Web/MattsTwitchBot.Web.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/MattsTwitchBot.Web"
RUN dotnet build "MattsTwitchBot.Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MattsTwitchBot.Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MattsTwitchBot.Web.dll"]
```

and the docker-compose for the solution (even without the Couchbase stuff I'm getting the same error, but I'm pasting it here for completeness):

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  couchbase:
    image: couchbase:6.5.0-beta2
    volumes:
    - "./couchbasetwitchbot:/opt/couchbase/var" # couchbase data folder
    ports:
    - "8091-8096:8091-8096" # https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/install/install-ports.html
    - "11210-11211:11210-11211"
  mattstwitchbot.web:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}mattstwitchbotweb
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: MattsTwitchBot.Web/Dockerfile
    environment:
      Couchbase__Servers__0: http://couchbase:8091/ # Reference to the "couchbase" service name on line 4
    depends_on:
    - couchbase # Reference to the "couchbase" service name on line 4
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "http://couchbase:8091"]
```

Comment: I paired with someone last night and everything seems to work okay from the command line; and everything worked okay *for him* from Visual Studio. At this point, I think blowing away Visual Studio might be a solution.

Comment: your repo is not reproducible. It comes up with a user error. Then certs issue. I was not able to make it work. Now, why would VS be an issue? Your code runs inside of a container.

Comment: I suspected VS because of this pairing session. I was able to run docker-compose from the command line and it seemed to work okay (and did not cause the getcwd error). When you say "my repo is not reproducible", what do you mean? What error did you get? I'm not getting a certs issue, neither did my pair. A "user error" (exception?) might be because you didn't enter twitch credentials, which means that you didn't run into the same issue as me.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have enough reputation to comment but I think it might be your .csproj file. You mentioned you upgraded Visual Studio. Since the .csproj file contains information about the project (including references to system assemblies), and you are copying it in your Dockerfile, it's possible that:

1. The .csproj file needs to be updated since you updated VS.
2. The dotnet core version in your dockerfile 'FROM' statement is a different version than what you're using locally.

Maybe test this by starting a new project and adding your source, then do a diff on the old and new .csproj files. You can also backup the original and try modifying the .csproj file manually. I found a [blog post](https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/03/09/vs2015-to-vs2017-upgrade/) that demonstrates upgrading a vs2015 csproj file to vs2017. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: My VS upgrade was a minor one: 16.4.3 to 16.4.4. I believe I tried a new project and a diff, but I didn't notice anything. Thank you for your answer, and it's worth me trying again.

Comment: @MatthewGroves Sorry I couldn't be more help. Good luck to you.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and am debugging code that has previously worked.  Simply closing my terminal and re-opening it resolved the issue for me.  I am using WSL, and have changed some environment variables that appear to have caused the initial issues.

Answer (score 1):

Because I don't have enough reputation I cannot comment on your question. 
But one thing that puzzles me is the fact that you are using as base image an image that doesn't have .Net SDK and if you try to run a command that requires an SDK looks it fails

I am assuming, in the container, `f93fb2962a1e` is using the image created by the docker file you posted in the question

Comment: I am not into the topic very deep. Can you explain more detailed how to solve your described issue?

Answer (score 1):

`getcwd()` error, means the solution lost context to path. I found that completely removing the `dock-compose` solution and the associated Dockerfile file from the project fixed the problem. It's hacky but works if you're in a bind.

Answer (score 0):

I belive that your current working directory got deleted or path to working directory was reseted. But it will be the first option because update of VS may removed directory `/tmp` on your docker machine so its not there anymore, and it will be created on some external event.

Or set port to blocking of connection to your docker machine.

1. Check connection to docker machine
2. Check existence of folder that is used as working directory on docker machine

If you didnt found problem then continue with this:

```
docker exec --it {containerID} /bin/sh
```

you can use this official docker [debugging article](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2019/10/31/inspecting-containers)
with this, follow the directories that is docker trying to access and check 
for their existence.

With this debugging you shoud be able to discover problems.

I hope that it helped you